# Application getting stuck in a specific screen without any error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have created an application for IOS. In which, I implemented chatting functionality there is a list of all conversion and when we click on the item from this list then it goes to chatting screen where we can type the message and can be send to second user.
In chatting screen, If there is already chat messages without any media then it works perfectly, On other hand, if there is no any chat messages or messages with media in chat history than it get stuck just after open the chat screen. It is not showing any error even not showing quite unexpectedly also.

Comment: You may be blocking the main thread - pause the execution (pause button on the debug controls) and inspect the stack trace to see what's currently running

Comment: There is nothing in stack trace, it's blank.

Comment: libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap:
    0x10d9f87b8 <+0>:  movq   %rcx, %r10
    0x10d9f87bb <+3>:  movl   $0x100001f, %eax          ; imm = 0x100001F 
    0x10d9f87c0 <+8>:  syscall 
->  0x10d9f87c2 <+10>: retq   
    0x10d9f87c3 <+11>: nop